# How can I click on any of the categories in the list and be redirected to all active listings in that category? Django

Tags: python, html, django, model

I`m working on a django project (i`m newb) and I`ve made a html page displaying a list of available categories. I want to make each a link and when the user clicks it he/she should be redirected to a list of active listings based on that category. I simply cannot understand how.
Here is my code:

```
models.py

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


class Listings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=822)
    price = models.FloatField()
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True, 
    related_name="listings_category")
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, related_name="select_category")
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

urls.py

path('category/', views.category, name="category"),

path("listing/<str:listing_id>", views.listing, name="listing")

views.py

def category(request):
    cat = Category.objects.filter().values('category')
    category_id = Category.objects.filter().values('id')
    z = []
    for c in category_id:
        z.append(c['id'])
    
    listing = Listings.objects.filter(category__in= z)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.filter(id__in=z)
    print(category)

    return render(request, "auctions/category.html",{
        "categories":categories,
        "category":category,
        "listing":listing
    })

def listing(request, listing_id):
        listing = Listings.objects.get(id=listing_id)
        user = request.user
        owner = True if listing.user == user else False
        category = Category.objects.get(category=listing.category)
        comments = Comments.objects.filter(listing=listing.id)
        watching = WatchList.objects.filter(user = user, listing = listing)
       
        if request.method == "POST":
            comment = request.POST["comment"]
            
            if comment != '':
                Comments.objects.create(user=user, listing=listing, comment=comment)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(listing_id)

        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                "listing": listing,
                "category": category,
                "owner": owner,
                "comments": comments,
                "watching": WatchList.objects.filter(user = user, listing = 
                listing).values('watching'),
            })
 

HTML

{% block body %}
    {% for cat in category %}
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">{{ cat.category }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I`ve got the link (Category) to render the html page with the list of available categories but I can`t link them to their respective active listings from the database.
Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a url for the listing list, and then a view that handles it, as well as a template.

in `urls.py`:

`path('category/<int:category_id>', views.listing_list, name="listing_list"),`

in `views.py` (make sure to set the template name in the render call):

```
def listing_list(request, category_id):
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    # use a reverse lookup on listings_category foreign key name
    listings = category.listings_category.all()

    return render(request, "auctions/<template name goes here>.html",{
        "category":category,
        "listings":listings
    })
```

In your template you will have the category object as well as all listings that belong to it in the context.

Then in your `auctions/category.html` you will need to change your HTML:

```
{% block body %}
    {% for cat in category %}
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'listing_list' category_id=cat.pk %}">{{ cat.category }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I`ve added your path in urls.py, then the function in views.py and also the template, but when I`m adding the url for the "Create" link the 'layout.html' I get NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'listing_list' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']. I tried `code` <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'listing_list' category.id %}">Category</a>
            </li> and a bunch of other url`s that came to mind. What am I missing?

Comment: Edited my answer, i was using `{% url "listing_list" category_id=category.pk %}` but it should have been `{% url "listing_list" category_id=cat.pk %}` as `cat` is the variable name you are using when you create the for loop